# Function doesn't work properly

Tags: php

I have this function in class called User

```
/**
* Function to get everything about specific user
* @access public
* @param string that user's email
* @param string that user's password
*/
public static function selectUser ( $email, $password )
{
    $result = mysql_query ( ' SELECT * FROM `modernt_mtalk`.`users` WHERE Email = ' . $email . ' AND Password = ' . md5($password) );

    if($result) {return $result;}
    else        {return false;}
}
```

and i call it in other file

```
require_once 'user.php';
$user = new User();

$info = $user -> selectUser('baronas15@gmail.com', 'root');

echo $info;
```

I put that data in so i can test if `echo $info` would give me anything. but that echo does nothing.

I know that it's not wrong data in `()` because i have other function that i tested with the same data and it works fine.
What's wrong?

Comment: First use print_r/var_dump instead echo in this case

Comment: Are you sure your SQL executed correctly?

Comment: thank's for those methods. but var dump told me that it returns false

Comment: Add ' at the end of query

Comment: well i now know that SQL is incorrect, i'll try something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you call a static function, you shouldn't encrypt the parameter since the function already does this for you:

```
$info = User::selectUser('baronas15@gmail.com', 'root'); //no need to encrypt twice
```

Also the query doesn't look correct, since email and password are not integers, they will need to be quoted:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `modernt_mtalk`.`users` WHERE Email = '". $email ."' AND Password = '". md5($password)."'");
```

Comment: well the code gets there, so static works fine in this case, it's just that i get false in return, somethings wrong with SQL

Comment: thanks, but the static works fine, i don't need that User:: it's just my SQL was wrong

Comment: welcome, you are also open to sql injection and using deprecated API, but I won't lecture you about it `;)`

Comment: i know that i'm open :D i should use mysql_real_escape_string but i first want to create main functionality, and test it so i can upgrade it later. it's easier for me this way

Answer (score 0):

That's because you parse already encrypted password which I suspect you shouldn't encrypt since you also encrypt it in your query so the method returns false. `var_dump` the result or display the "incorrect logins" if the method returns false

```
require_once 'user.php';
$user = new User();

if($info = $user -> selectUser('baronas15@gmail.com', 'root'))
     echo $info;
else
     echo 'Incorrect details';
```